# mysql query for getting related data from different table for suggested connections

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking

we are developing portal like social network site with different concept...but for doing suggested connections we got strucked in mysql queries...
we are trying to take users with similat data ...

```
SELECT u.* 
    FROM educonnect_user u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  educonnect_user_qualification q ON u.id = q.user_id 
    LEFT OUTER  JOIN educonnect_user_contact a1 ON u.id = a1.user_id 
WHERE q.type_of_institution in 
        (
            SELECT type_of_institution 
            FROM educonnect_user_qualification qi 
            WHERE qi.user_id = 3
         ) 
      AND q.college in 
         (
             select college 
             from educonnect_user_qualification qc 
             where qc.user_id = 3
          ) 
      AND q.country in 
          (
             select country 
             from educonnect_user_qualification qco 
             where qco.user_id = 3
          ) 
      AND a1.country in 
          (
             select country 
             from educonnect_user_contact cc 
             where cc.user_id = 3
          ) 
      AND a1.state in 
          (
             select state 
             from educonnect_user_contact cs 
             where cs.user_id = 3
          )
```

Like this I am joining 10 tables ..but the problem is wherever i gave `AND` operator no result generated and if i gave `OR` operator it returns all users ..its the logic these operator will give output which I know..but for this problem i need different suggestions which would work effectively..or else the query can be changed with any other specific operator???

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need all these `WHERE IN` conditions. You just need `where educonnect_user.user_id = 3` since the `educonnect_user` table is joined with the other two tables `educonnect_user_qualification` and `educonnect_user_contact`, therefore the join will insure that for the user with `id=3` the fields: `type_of_institution`, `college`, `country`,..( and other fields ) are exists in the two other tables for the same user, But you need to care about what type of join you need depending on what fields you want to select from your tables whether `Left`, `right`. So I think the following query what you are looking for:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM educonnect_user u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  educonnect_user_qualification q ON u.id = q.user_id 
LEFT OUTER  JOIN educonnect_user_contact a1 ON u.id = a1.user_id 
where u.user_id = 3
```

Comment: No mr.MGA the user_id = 3 is sample one..i want to get data from user_id =3 and from that data i want all matching user with similar data in db...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help ::

```
SELECT u.* 
    FROM educonnect_user u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  educonnect_user_qualification q ON u.id = q.user_id 
    LEFT OUTER  JOIN educonnect_user_contact a1 ON u.id = a1.user_id 
    left join educonnect_user_qualification qi on (q.type_of_institution=qi.type_of_institution and qi.user_id=3)
  left join educonnect_user_qualification qc  on (q.college=qc.college and qc.user_id=3)
  left join educonnect_user_qualification qco on (q.country=qco.country and qco.user_id=3)
  left join educonnect_user_contact cc on (a1.country=cc.country and cc.user_id=3)
  left join educonnect_user_contact cs on (a1.state=cs.state and cs.user_id=3)
```

Comment: mr sashi this is returning only user_id= 3  values..i want all the user matching the user_id= 3 record data

Comment: @Pushparaj: Have edited the query, plz check and revert back if any changes required